# Symfony Javascript Form Validation

Tags: php, javascript, forms, symfony1

So I have a form on my website that will submit a name and email address. I want to submit them with ajax which is simple to do, but I wanted to verify that both fields are filled in and that the email is in the correct email form.

Basically I want to run some client side validation on the fields before submitting it via ajax. Does anyone know how to do this with symfonys ajax remote helper methods?

Comment: Just throwing this out there:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

jQuery Validate. No AJAX, just good validation used by a large amount of people. Supports email :)

Comment: I've used that before. But I am interested in using JavaScript to validate a form prior to submitting it with AJAX, specifically with symfony. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Symfony 1.2 and sfForms, you can use a plugin called sfJqueryFormValidationPlugin:

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfJqueryFormValidationPlugin/0_9_1

It takes care of producing the right Javascript to validate fields. In your case, it'll just be checking that the fields have been filled.

This link has a more thorough tutorial:

http://blog.adryjanek.eu/2009/01/15/symfony-12-using-sfform-with-jquery-validate-plugin/

Hope this helps :)